# How can I stay on the same active link on page reload?

Tags: jquery

I have this script to indicate what nav link has an active style when I scroll to a specific ID on the page and this works fine, but if I reload the page this active style is set to the first link in the navigation and do not stay on the link pointing at this ID. How can this be fixed? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
  });

  // Cache selectors
  var topMenu = $("li.nav-item"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) {
        return item;
      }
    });

  // Bind to scroll
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

    // Get id of current scroll item
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
        return this;
    });
    // Get the id of the current element
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
    // Set/remove current_yes class
    menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("current_yes")
      .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("current_yes");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="nav-menu">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#to-top" class="nav-link">Hem</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#about" class="nav-link">Om</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#services" class="nav-link">Tjänster</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#projects" class="nav-link">Projekt</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Kontakta</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="hamburger">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Extract the contents of your `scroll` function into a named function and call it on page load as well as on scroll. Also, use `let` and `const` when writing JavaScript in 2023, not `var`.

Comment: From a quick look at your code it seems that the browser's URL will update with the hash in the URL when you click a nav link, is it the case? If so, on reload the page should scroll automatically to the corresponding anchor by itself (can you confirm it's the case?). However, when you scroll instead of clicking on a nav link, there is no code to add the hash to the URL, you should maybe just do that. Some browsers on refresh will try to scroll to the same value you were, but not all. Having a reproducible code with the HTML part would help us

Comment: Nothing in your code seems to save the active reference.  You can use cookies or local storage: ref:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage or send it to the server and store it there for the user.  Just refreshing the page does just that, refreshes - and saves nothing unless you tell it to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 500);

        let hashedId = $(this).attr('href');

        // Add the hash to history
        if (history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(null, null, hashedId);
        } else {
            location.hash = hashedId;
        }
        return false;
    });

    // Cache selectors
    let topMenu = $("li.nav-item"),
        topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 15,
        // All list items
        menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
        // Anchors corresponding to menu items
        scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
            let item = $($(this).attr("href"));

            if (item.length) {
                return item;
            }
        });

    // Bind to scroll
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        // Get container scroll position
        let fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

        // Get id of current scroll item
        let cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
            if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
                return this;
        });

        // Get the id of the current element
        cur = cur[cur.length - 1];

        let id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
        // Set/remove current_yes class
        menuItems
            .parent().removeClass("current_yes")
            .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("current_yes");

        let hashedId = "#" + id;

        // Add the hash to history
        if (history.pushState) {
            history.pushState(null, null, hashedId);
        } else {
            location.hash = hashedId;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello tank you, but this dit not work for me.

Comment: @PatrikIdén It's a good habit to take to be more precise on this site, "it did not work" is not a useful comment, the same way it's not useful in a question. Did it cause an error? did it change the behavior? is it only partially working? You also didn't answer when I asked for precisions. We are all trying to help people for free on this site, if people have to guess what's wrong, you'll get no answers.. All we have is a non-working code snippet

Comment: Sorry about that. The script works when i'm scrolling, but if i refresh the page there is no current yes class on any link.